# Net Beans can't execute jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, exe, executable-jar

So I'm fairly new to programming and recently started using net beans and even managed to do an application for my friends to use the only problem is that after I create jar file I can't execute it. I tried to make a simple program just for testing that will out print "hello world!" and realized that jar file doesn't run by double clicking. I looked for some solutions online and all i found is to use terminal to run or download additional software to make it run. Is there really no simple way to make it run form double clicking?

Comment: Yes, it runs also by double clicking but it opens and suddenly closes the terminal window. As far as it is a console application, running it from the terminal is the best option.

Comment: So it runs but its too fast for me to notice?? I tried double-clicking it with terminal open but nothing happened. It did however work when I used the command in terminal that net beans said to run to see if works

Answer (score 0):

Do you pause the execution of your code in any way?

If not your code may be executing properly, but too fast for you to see. Open a terminal and type `java -jar myjar.jar`. This way the window will not close after executing the program.